# Returning value in a nested function when using memoization

Tags: python, closures, dynamic-programming, memoization, nested-function

I am trying to implement a count variable in the function below using dynamic programming specifically memoization. The method calculates the value in a Fibonacci sequence at a given index. I cannot figure out why the count (in this case the number of times this program executes) is not returned.

```
def fibonacci_memoized():
    cached = {}
    count = [0]

    def fib(n):
        count[0] += 1
        if n in cached:
            return cached[n]
        elif n < 2:
            cached[n] = n
            return n
        elif n >= 2:
            cached[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
            return cached[n]

    return fib, count[0]


fib_calculation, c = fibonacci_memoized()
print("Memoized recursive Fibonacci sequence solution:", fib_calculation(given_index), "Execution:", c)
```

Output:

```
Memoized recursive Fibonacci sequence solution: 13 Execution: 0
```

Additionally, is this a good way to implement a method using dynamic programming in python, can this code be made better?

Comment: That's because you are returning `count[0]` instead of `count`

Comment: You can read this interesting discussion on [optimization of the computation of the series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Fibonacci_sequence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are returning `count[0]`, which is an integer. This doesn't get modified, the *reference* to `count[0]` does. So return `count` instead:

```py
def fibonacci_memoized():
    cached = {}
    count = [0]

    def fib(n):
        count[0] += 1
        if n in cached:
            return cached[n]
        elif n < 2:
            cached[n] = n
            return n
        elif n >= 2:
            cached[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
            return cached[n]

    # change this line
    return fib, count


# as a test, let's loop
fib_calculation, c = fibonacci_memoized()
for i in range(5):
    print(
        "Memoized recursive Fibonacci sequence solution:", 
        fib_calculation(i), 
        "Execution:", 
        c[0]
    )

Memoized recursive Fibonacci sequence solution: 0 Execution: 1
Memoized recursive Fibonacci sequence solution: 1 Execution: 2
Memoized recursive Fibonacci sequence solution: 1 Execution: 5
Memoized recursive Fibonacci sequence solution: 2 Execution: 8
Memoized recursive Fibonacci sequence solution: 3 Execution: 11
```

And to show the memoization works, we can run the loop a second time:

```py
for i in range(5):
    print(
        "Memoized recursive Fibonacci sequence solution:", 
        fib_calculation(i), 
        "Execution:", 
        c[0]
    )

Memoized recursive Fibonacci sequence solution: 0 Execution: 12
Memoized recursive Fibonacci sequence solution: 1 Execution: 13
Memoized recursive Fibonacci sequence solution: 1 Execution: 14
Memoized recursive Fibonacci sequence solution: 2 Execution: 15
Memoized recursive Fibonacci sequence solution: 3 Execution: 16
```